# C# Exception about not calling a function I already called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an application using ASP.NET MVC4. I am calling this code at the global.cs

```
    if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

as a part of the Application_Start() function which is the following:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);


        }
```

Which if I am right executes at the very beginning of the project.

I also have this code at a controller

```
 SimpleMembershipProvider provider = new SimpleMembershipProvider();
 MembershipUser user = provider.GetUser("testUser", false);
```

However, the second code produces an exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.
  Source=WebMatrix.WebData
  StackTrace:
       at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.get_PreviousProvider()
       at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)
       at UKFutureLiving_Team5.Controllers.TenantController.House() in c:\Users\nekta_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\UKFutureLiving_Team5\UKFutureLiving_Team5\Controllers\TenantController.cs:line 51
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
  InnerException:
```

and the message `"you must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site."` is shown.

Do you know why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you write this code into your `Application_Start` method?

Comment: yes. More specifically my application_start method is the following         `protected void Application_Start()
{
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
}`

Comment: @JimBlum edit your answer, don't write the code in the comments

Comment: Instead of putting in your globax.cs, did you do what the error message stated and put it in a _AppStart.cshtml file?

Comment: @Tommy I use aspx, so I do not have an _AppStart.cshtml file. Isn't the Global.asax.cs the responsible for this job for aspx?

Comment: @JNYRanger Thanks. I am doing it now

Comment: @JimBlum - then you might try a _AppStart.aspx file.  Also, you probably want to check your initialization before your call `AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();`.  Try it as the first thing your global.asax file.